# UI-Router - use $state.go or $location.path?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

What do you think is better using : $state.go or $location.path?

My animation doesn't work with state.go but do with $location.path.

Does any one know why?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide some lines of your code? If you define a url for your state then the `$location.path` changed automatically!

Comment: My code is very big. When I use the location.path() with the url I defined it works fine but when I use state.go with the state then the animation doesn't work.

Comment: How do you make the animation? Do you register event handlers? It is difficult to help without code details...

Comment: The animation is on the ui-view with ng-class that changed dynamically

Answer (score 4):

You can use the module [`ngAnimate`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate) instead of [`ngClass`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) directive to animate view/state changes. The module adds specific css classes on elements which changes. To see animations in action, you must only define the appropriate CSS classes

[Here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-animate-ui-view-with-ng-animate) you can find an small introduction how this with the ui-router module works.

**UPDATE**

Sorry for the delay... There is no reason why this shouldn't work. The UI-router plugin internally call `$state.go()` when `$location.path` changed.

See the forked [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GoKZJhGA3P14XNbzB9v9?p=preview) how `$state.go()` works in combination with [`ngAnimate`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate) module.

Comment: I am using angular 1.2+. And I am defining classes.

Comment: Maybe the angular animation cant work with state.go()?

Comment: I did saw it but there isn't any specific state.go calling so it is not my case. In my case I call specifically to state.go()